# I am a rookie and would appreciate assistance in solving this issue

Tags: css

Would someone mind assisting me with the CSS code I need to have these 4 boxes with the text resizing the boxes for mobile devices (phones)..

This is the website...  http://westmetrofire.stg.colorado.gov/

Here's the code (and I apologize I don't know how to use the coding section here)..  I think the issue is here (and I need to come up with another @media section that defines the phone screen size)...

```
@media (max-width: 950px) and (min-width: 450px) {
    .box {
        text-align: center;
        height: 180px;
```

I've tried several different things and the images gets all skewed.

Thanks for any assistance.  Jim

Comment: Please see our [tour] and [ask]. A [mre] is required to help you.

Comment: Using `@media` queries based on screen pixel dimensions is kinda passe now - you should consider using CSS `display: grid` with automatic tracks for _even better_ responsive layout without the need for explicit `@media` queries.

Comment: Remove your 'height: 180px' from this media query to resolve the text overflowing on mobile devices. I agree with @Dai that this can be accomplished without media queries. I'd recommend looking into flex positioning.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Thank you Maggie.,   That solved the issue (on my test page) !!!  I'll get it changed on the real site after lunch.  I'm trying so hard to wrap my head around some html/css.  It's a steep learning curve.  At least in this example I knew where the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Jim,

```
   @media (max-width: 450px)
      .box {
        height: 500px;
      }
```

I switched the .box height and was able to get the headings, paragraphs, and the images inside the boxes on what would be an iPhone 12 Pro display. This does however lead to some whitespace below since not all the elements inside each box are taking up the same space. I am also fairly new to CSS, however if this were me I would look into adding a class for each box so you can size them individually until everything fits. For example .box-red or .box-blue. These can then be added to the HTML elements and styled under that media query.

I'm almost certain there is an easier solution, but maybe this well help in the meantime.

Comment: Thank you !!  That solution worked and is similiar to the one above that just removed the height line.